# popup gets blocked , on second click its not blocked anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, blocked

when i click on button1 a ajax requests gets sended, if success a hidden button should be shown an clicked via jquery click() method.
The second button (button2) triggers an window.open event via jquery.

My problem is that on the first click the popup gets blocked on second click it isnt blocked anymore.I dont want that the popup is blocked.

I cant make it easier because i cant manipulate the second button.

Thanks for any help or solutions.

code:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="button1">button1</a>
<div style="display:none;" class="buttonhidden">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="button2">button2</a>
</div>  

$('.button1').click(function(){
    url="someurl";
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        async:    false,
        success:function(result){
            $('.buttonhidden').show(function(){
                $('.button2').focus().click();              
            });
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Where is the code for the window.open and why do you not use event.preventDefault() on the event handler for the link? and why click the button instead of executing code of its event handler?

Comment: try using `$('.button2').trigger('click');` instead of `$('.button2').focus().click();`

Comment: @Siva didn't change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a solution by switching btns on mouseenter 
but thanks for the help and idea's